# Pull API data real-time and publish

Tags: php, laravel, redis, socket.io

Info about the website I'm working:

Website related to soccer live score

API provides real-time data for soccer score (they got no webhooks)

What I want:

Want to deliver the real-time score in frontend

Also, I want to save that data in Redis temporarily and after the match finishes, want to push from Redis to the database.

Preferably don't use any external JS libraries ( http://socket.io ), pusher, etc. Laravel Broadcasting+ Redis is my preferred way since I won't need pusher or socket js code to load.

Parts of this problem:

Part 1: Pulling external API data to database(or Redis).
--> So far, the only way I've managed to pull data from the API to the database is, I've created a route which will trigger the load data from external API. Again, this is so useless as of now, because live score data in API is updated almost every second, and so far I need to trigger the route(or refresh the URL every second) just to pull up data from API. Also, not to forget, it will take 2-3 minimum second just to completely transfer API data to the database. This section is not dependant on whether to pull only if the user(frontend is requesting). It should do its job even if there are 0 users online.

So, my question is what is the best, most efficient and complete way to pull API data real-time and save it in Redis until the match is finished? (we can know the status of the match by checking in API data example: {match_id{status: finished}}xxxx). Because after the match is finished, I will push Redis to the database.

Part 2: Publishing that data real-time from the database(or Redis).
-> Okay this one for me is fairly easier than part 1, I've already found ways to publish Redis data real-time via pusher and socket.io. But other than that, what is the best way to do in my scenario? Also, do I need any JS libraries if I have to use a combination of Redis+ Laravel broadcasting?

Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Possible answer for part 1:

I would use [Task Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/master/scheduling) to `->daily();` or `->hourly();` an [Artisan Console](https://laravel.com/docs/master/artisan) Command to check when the next soccer match is and write a record in the `matches` table, or update existing records in case the start/end time changes.

Another Console Command on `->cron('* * * * *');` (change to desired seconds) that executes every few seconds can check the `matches` table; if the current time is between the `starts_at` and `ends_at` of a match, retrieve realtime data.

To prevent multiple executions of the command (if for some reason an API call takes a bit longer) at the same time, Symfony's [Lockable Trait](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/lockable_trait.html) might be used.

Comment: Well the point is, "every few seconds" might be a problem, since it is a live score platform, I need to be able to deliver the real time, so I was looking for how I can retreive real time data rather than when/ conditions for task scheduling.  As you said, lets say after task scheduling, we find a match just now, so I am looking for something that can pull data from API and save it in my redis/ database.  We can do a http request every few seconds to pull data from API, but it is inefficient, and have to wait few seconds everytime to get updated data. I'm looking for something like (1/3)

Comment: streaming the real time API data. After that the part two is easier for me. I can deliver this via socket.io or pusher etc... 
In an ideal situation, I'm looking for something like: task schedluing triggers a command that tells match is starting now, xxx <--- this idea/library/ whatever we call it goes to API and pulls real time streaming of data to my redis cache. In the frontend, redis cache will be delivered by socket.io in real-time. After match finishes, redis data goes to database. So, my question is what is that xxx, other than http request (2/3)

Comment: that is efficient, reliable and cost low resources. (3/3)

Comment: Quite a challenge. Sorry, my knowledge does not go that far.

Comment: If I were you I would post a new question focusing on the first part, because this one is already a few days old and receiving little attention.